# Convert byte buffer to UTF8 string

Tags: c#, sockets, utf-8, character-encoding, bytebuffer

With this function I convert received bytes into unicode string:

```
//MESSAGE READER
String message = null;
byte[] b = new byte[2048];
int k = Socket.Receive(b);
char c = ' ';
for (int i = 0; i < k - 1; i++)
{
    c = Convert.ToChar(b[i]);
    message += c.ToString();
}
```

How can I convert it to UTF-8 string instead of unicode?

**EDIT:**
*Convert.ToChar* - Converts the value of the specified 8-bit unsigned integer to its equivalent Unicode character.
Is there some function that converts to equivalent UTF-8 character?

Comment: A single UTF8 can consist of multiple bytes.

Comment: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your incoming data is in UTF-8 format, then you can just pass the byte array directly to `Encoding.UTF8.GetString` to get the string representation of the UTF-8 data.

```
byte[] b = new byte[2048];
int k = Socket.Receive(b);    
string message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b, 0, k);
```

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thank you. Incoming data is in UTF-8 format, so I only had to change "GetString(b, 0, k);" into "GetString(b, 0, k-1);"

Answer (score 4):

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(message));
```

Comment: With this I get only first character from message...?

Comment: @mgulan no you get the entire message, if it fits within the buffer.